# How to restore a VM if the source is deleted from a vault

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I do not want to pay for the extra premium storage costs and I would like to backup my server to a storage vault. And restore when I want. How is that possible?

Reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a snapshot of a VM disk. You can take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk) article.

For UI way check screenshot below. Open the existing disk properties and click that.
[image]

Comment: There is no way to take a snapshot of a VM via UI button ?

Comment: I do not see this in mine.

Comment: i don't think there is a way to do that from the portal if you are not using managed disk

Comment: Ahaa... Than the problem is I am using an unmanaged disk.https://image.prntscr.com/image/xQlYbEn8SmWUFX4ZFPiCGg.png

Comment: one way to do that - would be go to the storage account, locate the blob and download it. or you can use azcopy to copy it somewhere (I believe)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Than I have to take the snapshot with PowerShell. And the next time I start my machine I have to first create a managed disk than start my machine otherwise.I can not take a snapshot.

Comment: Remember to shutdown your machine prior to snapshot as in unmanaged disk the snapshot is not application consistent.

Comment: I was able to restore the VM even though it is not managed! After taking the backup it gave me the option. https://i.hizliresim.com/gWyX63.png

Comment: Thanking a snapshat killed my VM in DevTest Labs... Not all captures are created equal!!!!

Comment: Also backing up was not cheap at Azure. I was shocked at how much money I owed MS after the backup Vault. Not realistic to use.